# Samsung devices requiring large heap size in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I've created an Android game which uses a few full screen bitmaps (4 @ 800x480) and maybe 10 Sprites (about 80x80), so it's not particularly large. The game runs absolutely fine on an old HTC Desire with 100mb free ram and 25mb free storage. It also runs fine on several high end HTC phones, a Motorola XOOM tablet, Nexus 5, Nexus 7 and a couple of Archos/Arnova tablets. However when I run it on a Samsung device (currently Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0) it gives an out of memory error in the bitmap load area of the code which can only be resolved by setting the large heap request to true in the android manifest xml which is a outrageous since this has to be then set on all devices unless I create a separate app in the Play store). I initially thought this might be due to the images being loaded from the drawable area, so changed this to assets but it makes no difference. Anybody else encountered this issue and found a fix for it ?

The lines which fail are either:-

```
retBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res.getAssets().open(name+".png"));
```

or

```
retBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, res.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", con.getPackageName()));
```

Depending on whether I'm loading from assets or drawable, I've also tried using this option before:-

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); options.inPurgeable = true;
```

but it makes no difference. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `options.inSampleSize = 2`;

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: it is a value that If is set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

Comment: Can you edit that back into your answer? Generally, code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't help the viewer understand how to use it, unless it's very obvious. The above explanation is helpful, and should be part of the answer.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but still gives an out of memory error on the bitmap load. The sprites are pretty small anyway, and the 4 backdrops are only 800x480, they shouldn't need sampling.

Comment: try https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html but first try inSampleSize = 4

Comment: I've tried up to 8 and it's still failing. I can't really use that setting anyway as it would degrade the image quality too much. Part of the problem is I have to have 4 background images loaded in to memory at any one time to allow for smooth directional scrolling in game. It doesn't even get to the point where I create the background buffer, but fails on this load bitmap section of the code for these backgrounds. I've read the Google article you mention but it doesn't really address this issue (it's more about caching large numbers of bitmaps for one off display). But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your bitmaps not in single UI event.
As I checked - android can increase application heap size between UI events.

You may use some custom solution to implement **Application Data Initialization** entity in async way and show some initalization screen (for ex. with some animation) - common practice.

For example you may use sequence of Runnable to load set of Bitmaps and after last resource is loaded notify application about your **Application Data Loading Finished Event**.

```
initHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
    /* load bitmap */
    /* post new runnable if not all bitmaps loaded */
    /* in  other case notify user about loding finished */
});
```

To check this approach - use next command and analyse **native heap size**:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.your.package.name
```

As you may know - android stores bitmap data in **native buffers** (starting from some version).

I believe async bitmap loading may fix your issue.